# Place second list at same position as first list in beamer overlay

Tags: beamer, itemize, two-column, overlays

I like to have the second itemize list to appear at the top of the frame, i.e. at the same place as the previous itemize list.
At this frame I have two columns where each item on the left column are associated with several items which I like to be appeared on the right column after each item on the left column. Then, item list associate with first item on right should disappear and again the item list associate to second item on the left should start from the top of the frame.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {

\usetheme{Hannover}
\usecolortheme{seagull}
}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{siunitx} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{ applications}

\begin{columns}

    \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}

    \begin{itemize}
   \setbeamercovered{transparent}
\item <1-5> {\small Combustion}
\item<6-> {\small Airborne }
\item<10->{\small Environmental}

\end{itemize}

\end{column}

\begin{column}{7cm}

\begin{itemize}[label={}]

\item[] <2-5>{\tiny PN$\mathrm{_{ d< 1\,\si{um}}}$ $\gg$ PN$\mathrm{_{ d> 1\,\si{um}}}$     }
\item[] <2-5>{ \tiny A correlation }
\item[] <3-5>{\tiny No universal }
\item[] <4-5> {\tiny limited}

\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}[label={}]

\item[] <7-7>{\tiny PN$\mathrm{_{ d< 1\,\si{um}}}$ $\gg$ PN$\mathrm{_{ d> 1\,\si{um}}}$     }

\end{itemize}

\end{column}

\end{columns}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can use the `{}` to format code blocks -- or simply indent them by 4 spaces. It is easier to help you if you add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you - and much more likely that they will!

Comment: @Andrew: I am not sure how that can help to reset the position of the second item list to the frame top.

Comment: i think the title would be clearer with "above" instead of "on top of"; i read this as "the second list should overprint the first".  ("over" doesn't work either.)  didn't want to change the title without your agreement.

Comment: @Ramin By giving a minimal example that compiles you give people  initial code to work from. If you give only partial code, without the documentclass and relevant packages, people have to guess these things and they have to spend extra time to set things up before they even think about helping you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `overprint` environment with an `\onslide` before each `itemize`.  Schematically

```
\begin{column}{0.55\textwidth}
  \begin{overprint}
    \onslide<2-5>
    \begin{itemize}
    \item<2-5> text 
    \item<3-5> text
    \end{itemize}
    \onslide<7>
    \begin{itemize}
    \item<7> text
    \end{itemize}
  \end{overprint}
\end{column}
```

On slide 5 you then have

[image: Slide 5]

and slide 7 has

[image: Slide 7]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>{
\usetheme{Hannover}
\usecolortheme{seagull}
}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-all}

\newcommand{\PN}{\textsf{PN}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{applications}

  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
      \small
      \begin{itemize}
        \setbeamercovered{transparent}
      \item<1-5> Combustion
      \item<6-> Airborne
      \item<10-> Environmental
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}

    \begin{column}{0.55\textwidth}
      \tiny
      \begin{overprint}
        \onslide<2-5>
        \begin{itemize}
        \item[]<2-5>$\PN_{\mathrm{d}< \SI{1}{um}} \gg
          \PN_{\mathrm{d}>\SI{1}{um}}$
        \item[]<2-5>A correlation
        \item[]<3-5>No universal
        \item[]<4-5>limited
        \end{itemize}
        \onslide<7>
        \begin{itemize}
        \item[]<7>$\PN_{\mathrm{d}< \SI{1}{um}} \gg
          \PN_{\mathrm{d}>\SI{1}{um}}$
        \end{itemize}
      \end{overprint}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I have tidied up several other aspects of your code

- moved the text sizing commands outside of the lists, as they applied to all elements
- used `\SI{1}{um}` rather than `1\,\si{um}` for print numbers with a unit, and added the `detect-all` feature so the font matches
- collected math expressions in to single units, with a command to typeset PN in the sans font
- specified the second column width relative to the textwidth
- replaced overlay specification `<7-7>` by `<7>`